# Create hash/fingerprint of json - best (fast) way

Tags: json, md5, fingerprint

I need to create some hash/fingerprint of my json data to detect if they are changed.

Right now, I am using md5 but I thing there is a faster way how to create this hash/fingerprint.

What should I use?

I don't need some secure, I just need some print of my json.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of options here.  First, you can use BLAKE2b, which is faster than MD5 (and also secure, unlike MD5).  It's a cryptographic hash function, and you can be confident if the hashes match that the files are the same, and if they don't match, they're different.  GNU coreutils has `b2sum` and recent versions of OpenSSL have `blake2b512` as an algorithm; there are various other implementations as well.

The other solution is to use something like CRC64.  This can be slightly faster than BLAKE2b, but is not secure against any sort of tampering, and because it's only 64 bits in size, you can end up with accidental collisions.  If those are acceptable in your situation because all your data is trusted and your data set is small, then it can be a fine option.  You can find open-source implementations in a variety of places online.

There's no reason to use MD5 because it's slower than both of these options and it's also insecure, unlike BLAKE2b.